# Share embed content on facebook using swf player

Tags: php, html, facebook, flash, facebook-graph-api

In order to share an Html content in facebook (witch may not be possible), i saw a trick using Open graph protocol and a SWF Player so the post will be treated as video post .

Exemple ([link](https://mintsapp.io/poll/view/1395)) :

```
<meta property="og:title" content="What anti agin method do you preffer?">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://mintsapp.io/uploads/polls/5639037a63bed.jpg" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://mintsapp.io/poll/view/1395" />
<meta property="og:video" content="https://mintsapp.io/player/player.swf?id=1395&type=poll&token=567dcd401fb74&voteChoiceId=3172" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://mintsapp.io/player/player.swf?id=1395&type=poll&token=567dcd401fb74&voteChoiceId=3172" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="472" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="355" />
```

and when it comes to share this page on facebook , it will be treated like a video and an html content will be compiled using that SWL player , its actually load the html content and display it as flash content . 
see this link : https://mintsapp.io/player/player.swf?id=1395&type=poll&token=567dcd401fb74&voteChoiceId=3172

I need to understand how to do something similar to that, because i've been googling the whole day with no results.

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this

Comment: why ? can you explain to me please ?